# How to get rid of the unwanted space around plotoutput in shiny?

Tags: r, plot, shiny

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGbHJ.jpg)I have 2 plot outputs that are shown uder each other (using 2 plotoutputs in shiny). But there is a whitespace around the plots which is unnecessary, and I could not get rid of it using css styling such as (padding=0). I would like to have the plots beneath each other with no space between.
I would appreciate any advice! Thanks

Comment: This is probably due to the margins of the plot. Try `par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))` before `plot(......)`.

Comment: I tried the above, but still it does not work. I just attached the plot in my question above (enter image description here), and you can see the space which I have circled with blue.